# Laravel 5.3 : Unique validation not working with where condition with primary key !='id'

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and want to add validation of unique url with where clause in update case. I have tried both codes but none seems to be working.

```
    'page_url' => [ 'required',
                        Rule::unique('pages')->ignore($id_page,'id_page')
                ],


    'page_url' => 'required|unique:pages,page_url,null,null,id_page,!'.$id_page,
```

Error

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pages.id' in 'where clause'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use this 'page_url' => 'required|unique:pages,page_url,'.$id_page

Comment: Tried, giving same error.

Comment: what is your column name for page id? if it is different than id then try 'page_url' => 'required|unique:pages,page_url,'.$id_page.',id_page'

Comment: Tried already.....both not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by adding this in model:

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'id_page';
```